# Android Tablet App Quality - dimensions customization

Tags: android, tablet

Tablet App Quality guide says, that to make good tablet version of the app developer should:
"At a minimum, customize dimensions such as font sizes, margins, spacing for larger screens, to improve use of space and content legibility".

For phones its known, that default text size = 16sp and default screen margins = 16dp, [with good exploration and demo](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html#48dp-rhythm).

What are recommended values for default text size and margins for 7inch and 10inch tablets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got useful info [here](http://parleys.com/play/52adb157e4b04354fb7e7abb/chapter68/about).

Its mentioned, that for sw720dp tablets default screen margin = 32dp and text size = 20sp.